# What does 'them' refer to in the passage?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does ***them*** refer to ***gifted children***, or ***things that happen in the world***?
What I think is if ***them*** refers to ***things that happen in the world***, the preposition before ***them*** should be ***to*** instead of ***for***, am I right?

> It is vitally important that gifted children are taught to see their
> heightened sensitivity to things that happen in the world as a normal
> response for ***them***. If this is not made clear to them, they may
> see their own intense inner experiences as evidence that something is
> wrong with them. Other children may ridicule a gifted child for
> reacting strongly to an apparently trivial incident, thereby
> increasing the child's feeling of being odd. Also, sensitivity to
> society's injustice and hypocrisy can lead many emotionally intense
> gifted children to feel despair and cynicism at very young ages.

[Emotional Intensity In Gifted Children](https://www.pvschools.net/sites/default/files/Academics/Academic%20Programs/Gifted/Emotional%20Intensity%20in%20Gifted%20Children.doc.pdf)

Comment: 'Them' here refers to the gifted children. You are right about the logic of 'for' vs. 'to' but that doesn't apply here. I don't know enough about the grammar rules here to a provide you with a full answer, sorry. Hopefully someone else can

Comment: Yes - in this exact context, the choice between ***for*** and ***to*** completely and unambiguously reflects whether ***them*** refers to ***gifted children*** or ***things that happen***. There isn't really anything else to say about it, other than to point out that the *second* type of preposition usage is already there in *heightened sensitivity **to** things* (which for those children is a normal response ***to*** those things).